# Soll ich "unser achter Hund" or "unser achte Hund" schreiben?

Tags: pronoun, numbers, declension-table

Diese Frage ist vielleicht sehr einfach, ich bin aber noch Anfängerin.

So wie ich das sehe, verweist  "unser" schon auf das Genus. Soll ich dann "achte" hier nutzen?

Comment: Hast Du einen ganzen Satz? https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:acht

Comment: Es muss _unser achter Hund_ heissen.

Comment: I think three dogs would be more than enough.

Comment: For those who voted for close: how would one guess the table one should refer to? I think that's the question, is not that the OP doesn't know she might look it up there.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann That depends on whether it is meant synchronically or diachronically ;-)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Dog_Night

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf  That's a viable argument. On the other hand, even diachronically eight dogs are a lot. What are they doing with them that they are so short-lived? Should we call the police?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Maybe they always take older dogs from an animal shelter? Perhaps they consider their home a single-dog animal sanctuary?

Comment: Thanks! That's just an excersice from my coursebook (though I agree it is rather weird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wenn ich die Frage richtig verstehe, geht es um eine Regel, die ungefähr besagt: Wenn das Artikelwort das Genus anzeigt, wird das Adjektiv schwach flektiert. Artikelwörter, die das Genus anzeigen, wären z.B. *der, dieser, jeder, welcher …* und die entsprechenden neutralen Formen *das, dieses, jedes, welches …* Dagegen sowohl maskulin als auch neutral und damit nicht genusanzeigend können *ein, mein, kein …* sein, auf die starke Adjektive folgen.

> jed**er** jung**e** Hund – kein jung**er** Hund

Der Possessivartikel *unser* gehört zu *mein* und ist endunglos; das *-er* entspricht nicht der Endung von *der, dieser* etc. sondern gehört zum Stamm. Das sieht man z.B., wenn tatsächlich eine Endung auftritt:

> Wir mußten mit unser**em** Hund zum Tierarzt. (*nicht:* unsem)

Oder auch am Pronomen:

> A: Mein Hund bellt oft.
>   B: Mein**er** (=mein Hund) bellt auch oft! / Unser**er** (=unser Hund) bellt auch oft!

Da das *-er* von *unser* zum Stamm gehört und keine Endung darstellt, muß es heißen:

> unser acht**er** Hund

wie

> mein acht**er** Hund

Comment: Danke schön! :)